# Retrieving image in scoped storage Android 11

Tags: java, mediastore, android-external-storage, android-11, scoped-storage

I'm working on scanner app. My problem is while retrieve saved image from scoped storage in Android 10 and 11. Image is saved successfully but I am not able to retrieve it. When I get path of save image bitmap is `null`.
Here is the code to save the image in Android 11:

```java
File dirDest = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES, context.getString(R.string.app_name));
Long date = System.currentTimeMillis();
String extension = ".jpg";

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, date + extension);
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/" + extension);
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, date);
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED, date);
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE, bitmap.getByteCount());
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.WIDTH, bitmap.getWidth());
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.HEIGHT, bitmap.getHeight());
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, dirDest + File.separator);
    Uri newImageUri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
    FileOutputStream fos = (FileOutputStream) resolver.openOutputStream(Objects.requireNonNull(newImageUri));
    callback.write(fos);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
    return String.valueOf(dirDest) + date + extension;
```

Here is the code to retrieve the save image from shared storage in scoped storage in Android 11. I am getting issue in this part of code, bitmap is `null`. I am not getting the main point of the problem. In the end the problem is `FileNotFoundException`.

```java
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    String[] file = {MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
    MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH,
    MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
    MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE,
    MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE,
    MediaStore.Images.Media.WIDTH,
    MediaStore.Images.Media.HEIGHT,
    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED};
    if (uri != null) {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, file, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            try {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(file[0]);
                File path = new File(uri.getPath());
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path.getAbsolutePath());
                cursor.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Here is the code to retrieve the save image from shared storage in scoped storage in android 11" -- if `Uri` is what you got from `insert()` on the `ContentResolver` earlier, then none of those lines make any sense. Instead, call `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver`, passing in your `Uri`, to get an `InputStream` on the content. Then, pass that `InputStream` to `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()`. Or, better yet, consider one of the many image-loading libraries that are available, such as Glide or Picasso.

Comment: Your code also seems to be missing brackets. Copied it wrongly?

Answer (score 0):

You can query them all with the help of [SimpleStorage](https://github.com/anggrayudi/SimpleStorage):

```kotlin
val images: List<MediaFile> = MediaStoreCompat.fromMediaType(applicationContext, MediaType.IMAGE)
images.forEach { 
    println(it.absolutePath)
}
```